# Input referred noise of two port networks

Tags: circuit-analysis

I am given some noisy black-box two-port networks whose Y-parameter & output noise spectrum is known (when output is open or short). I need to find the input referred noise for:

1. Each individual network
2. When two of them are connected in parallel
3. When two of them are connected in cascade

What is the systematic way of solving this?

Comment: Modeling a network with Y-parameters and the output is open is likely to lead to unsolvable equations.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.